how can i get the requirement amended date
i would like to ask how can i get the amended date in this link:https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/regulations/standardnumber/1910/1910.95?
should i use api? or i can use python scraping? but it says access deny through python.***
i have already try this code in python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/regulations/standardnumber/1910/1910.95"
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
}
发送GET请求获取页面内容
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
检查请求是否成功
if response.status_code == 200:
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
# 查找class为field--name-field-fr-citations的元素
citations = soup.find_all(class_='field--name-field-fr-citations')

for citation in citations:
    print(citation.get_text(strip=True))

else:
print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
print(response.text)  # 输出错误信息
